# Is there a way of restoring data in Postgres DB from a dump in the order they were inserted in original DB to avoid violating check constraint?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

There is table `accounts` in the original DB, which I need to clone. 
I created a dump with

```
pg_dump --verbose --host=my_host --port=5432 --username=postgres --format=c -n "core" -n "public" my_database -f dumpfile
```

when restoring from the dump by

```
pg_restore --host=another_host --port=5432 --username=postgres --format=c -d my_database dumpfile
```

I'm getting error:

```
COPY failed for table "accounts": ERROR:  new row for relation "accounts" violates check constraint "valid_parent_account"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (685d6529-cd0a-41be-be5a-c9aea60aa8c5, 139788c6-197f-40f1-a7f7-274a23af9062, null, t, 2020-02-06 15:05:18.571918, 2020-03-24 16:14:47.061383, null, null, null, null, null).
```

it's because `core.accounts`'s DDL is:

```
CREATE TABLE core.accounts (
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    parent_id uuid NULL,
...
    CONSTRAINT valid_parent_account null
);
```

and function `core.valid_parent_account` is :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION core.is_valid_parent_account(parent_account_id uuid)
 RETURNS boolean
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare good boolean;
BEGIN   
    good := false;
    if (parent_account_id is null) or (exists(select 1 from core.accounts where id = parent_account_id and parent_id is null)) then
         good := true;
    end if;

    return good;
END;
$function$
;
```

which means 
that a row has to have either `parent_id` = NULL or existing `id` from the same table. The condition result depends on the insertion order. If it is not the same as it was of original table, it violates constraint and results in the error above.

I tried restoring schema and data separately by `pg_restore -s` and  `pg_restore ---disable-triggers --data-only --superuser=postgres` after it. It didn't help: constraint is not trigger.

I guess it can be done by removing(or modifying) the function and then adding it back. But I would like to put dump/restore to script. And this wouldn't be universal solution. Is there a way to solve this elegantly?

Comment: Why don't you do that with a proper foreign key? Then you could restore the dump without any problems

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's legacy DB which I'm not allowed to modify at the moment